# concurrent collections in python

Tags: python, collections, concurrency

I was wondering if there was any concurrent structure like `queue` in python but with the ability to remove a specific element.

Example:

```
import queue

#with queue would be
q = queue.Queue()
#put some element
q.put(elem)

#i want to delete a specific element
#but queue does not provide this method
q.remove(elem)
```

What could I use?

Comment: Just a `list`…?

Comment: First explain why are you using queue in the very first place? A queue has by default nature of FIFO so `list` might be a better option here

Comment: queue is just an example of  thread-safe structure, is list thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

Actually Python lists work like what you are looking for. As a matter of fact, the translation of your code (which requires no imports) should look like this:

```
#Create the list
q = [element1, element2, element3...]

#Insert element
q.insert(position, element4)

#Insert element in the end
q.append(element4)

#Remove element
del(q[position])
```

So that you can manage it as desired.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: They are, but if you want to absolutely make sure, there are methods to control it, check this article for instance:

http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-threads-synchronization-locks-rlocks-semaphores-conditions-events-and-queues/